# Directory watcher with java.nio.file.WatchService - how to register the information for Event tracking

Tags: java, file, directory

The title is maybe not detailed enough.

I have an application that is dealing with app installation (it does thing as creating backup file, copying and also **deleting** file) - I call it AppUpdater. Then I do have another Application that is tracking certain directory with java.nio.file.WatchService lib - lets call it DirWatcher. I have used this example: https://kodejava.org/how-to-monitor-file-or-directory-changes/

What I really want is to be able to recognized whether file in that certain location is updated by the AppUpdater or for example manually by user. Is there anyway to register/log some information while modifying file with AppUpdater, so that I will know that the update came from AppUpdater?
Thanks